# Download any files by WebClient Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, webclient, dwg

I try to download .dwg file by WebClient like this:

```
if (document.QueryString.ContainsKey("url"))
{
    Uri url = new Uri(s+document.QueryString["url"]);

    WebClient webclient = new WebClient();

    webclient.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;
    webclient.OpenReadAsync(url);
}

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File download complete");

        Stream stream = e.Result;
        StreamReader streamREader = new StreamReader(stream);
        List<string> ii = new List<string>();

        listbox.Items.Add(streamREader.ReadToEnd());
        //files.Add(stream.ToString(), new BinaryReader(stream));
    }
}
```

Directory "files" contain 2 files:
files/1.txt
files/2.dwg
I can download 1.txt, but when i'm downloading 2.dwg
webclient throws new exception "NotFound".
How to download any file by webclient in the Silverlight
or is there anyone else mehod to download files?
I use the following line to access the file:
mySite:13866/testWebTestPage.aspx?url=files/1.dwg

Answer (score 0):

> mySite:13866/testWebTestPage.aspx?url=files/1.dwg

Where is protocol("http://" or "https://") part gone?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.95).aspx - is network politics file writen and placed on target host?

Comment: http://localhost:13866/testWebTestPage.aspx?url=files/1.dwg is real path and ClientAccessPolicy.xml on yhe host